# How can I force symbol a symbol reference in c++ (programmatically)

Tags: c++, dll, reference, symbols

I'm trying to plug tcmalloc into a suite of software that we currently use at work. The software comprises of a lot of dll's. They all refer to a shared header file, so I can pragma link the library.

However as none of the code refers to the symbol __tcmalloc the optimizer strips the dll. Now I don't want to have to edit 200 project files and add symbol references in each one.
So my question is, is there a way to add a symbol reference programmatically?

To add some clarity I am compiling under Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, for anyone searching to the answer to this it's as follows

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/include:__tcmalloc")
```